# How to create rows automatically with Apache POI?

Tags: apache, apache-poi, xls

I'm working in a  project in Java and I Need to create one xls file with some information.
So,  depending on the amount of information, I need to create automatically Rows and cells to put this information..

Example: if the input documents has 13 Site Information, I need to create 13 Rows with 4 cell..
How I do it?
..
my attempt to code:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

    int numberrows = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "numbers of sites??"));


    String siteName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Site name");
    String rncname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "RncName");


    for (int i = 0; i < numberrows; i++) {
        HSSFRow linha =  (HSSFRow) sheet.createRow(i);

        linha.createCell((short) i ).setCellValue(siteName);
        linha.createCell((short) i ).setCellValue(rncname);

    }
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you not just do something simple like:

```
int nextRow = 12;

Row r = sheet.getRow(nextRow);
if (r == null) {
    r = sheet.createRow(nextRow);
}

Cell c = r.getCell(2, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
c.setCellValue("My String");

nextRow++;
```

Comment: This will help me to create automatically a mount of rows that I need? 'Cause I try and does not work like I want  >< ><

Comment: Thanks , My problem is Solved.. for those who want to know how  I did it,  I did the new rows with MainRow + 1 every loop...